# Which Employee ( avoid if conditional to change )

Tags: google-sheets

This file is like a transaction orders page , i want my employee to select his name ( ex. employee A ) , then for any one who write the order ( ex. ADB ) the sheet fill which employee do that depend on the checkbox ( Tick box ).

i used this :

```
=if(E2<>"", if($A$2=True,"A",if($B$2=True,"B",if($C$2=True,"C","Some Thing Wrong"))),"")
```

The problem is :
if employee B change the check box to his check box all ( who ) column change to B and either employee A who do it before so on.

Can i force the if condition to keep the first selection and dont change later ?!
This what i need

[image: What i need]

But this what happened

[image: What happen]

Ex.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nJ_-hfsfDTZYD-weULdB4Swg97Bd6v4iiXjXANtve7Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The linked spreadsheet hasn't the same structure shown on the screenshots and there isn't a description about how it relates to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i force the if condition to keep the first selection and dont change later ?

You have to replace the formula by it's value. To do this automatically you will have to use a script. To learn about how to do this, read [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).

Considering that you will use a script, perhaps it will be better to make the whole thing with the script, in other words, put the conditional on the script rather than using a formula.